# I seem to be missing something when it comes to setting up Firebase. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, gradle

I'm following these instructions to set up Firebase:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

but from step 1 section 2 things go wrong. When I put the required command into any directory, be it command prompt, node.js, or firebase CLI nothing happens and I get error messages like the following:

> 'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Flutter is set up correctly with android studio as I've been following instructions and building apps to practice.

The whole set up process is a nightmare and there are few videos that help. Most also focus on ios over windows.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be a huge help as I don't want to continue until I know things are working right.

I have managed to login to the CLI with my firebase account and have registered my projects, I can also recall these in CLI as a list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even just a link to a decent walkthrough app.

Comment: Looks you haven't added the Flutter SDK path to the environment variables: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

It seems operating system issue, run `dart --version` I am sure you will find the same result.
If so you need to add flutter and dart to your environment variables.

Follow **update your path** section on : https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

You can run 'flutter doctor -v' on the root folder of your project to see everything works fine after updating your path.